# How to position dropdown menu on hover to desired location?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I want to create this menu where on hover a dropdown menu appears and normally I would have no trouble doing this setting the UL to top:100%.  However this time I need it to be further down but it needs to be precised so it is cross browser friendly.  So what I tried is to set a margin-top:17px to the UL container to push it away from the top and that works but as soon as I hover over it, the dropdown closes.  I added a RED border in the example to show where I would like the dropdown UL top to start.

Please have a look -> [Link to example](http://jsfiddle.net/BZpLf/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `margin-top` to `padding-top` - http://jsfiddle.net/BZpLf/2/

```
#main-nav ul ul {display:none;position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;padding-top:17px;min-width:150px;background-color:#272727;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);}
```

Also the background-color is changed from `#000` to `#272727`

Comment: Hello can you tell me what you did?  Just changing margin to padding should not of worked because that would mean the background color would bleed into the top...so did you change something else?

Comment: See this-> http://jsfiddle.net/BZpLf/6/  You can see if you use padding instead, the background would bleed in...

Comment: Make the `ul ul` background transparent and give the red background to `ul ul li` - http://jsfiddle.net/BZpLf/7/

Comment: oK thx...however is this the only way?  Because what if I wanted a border around the dropdown UL container?  Then how would this work?

Comment: GIve your `#main ul li` a height of 45px and remove the padding stuff entirely from `ul ul` - http://jsfiddle.net/BZpLf/8/ - green border added :)

Comment: I will mark this as resolved, thx for the insights...if you have time, I have one more challenge for you...What if I want a border around the button on hover?  If you add it now, on hover, it will shift the text which is unwanted.  But this needs to be dynamic and we cannot give a set width to the li or a elements...a solution for that? http://jsfiddle.net/BZpLf/10/

Comment: you have to give your `li` a transparent border, like `li { border: 2px solid transparent }` and later change just the color from `transparent` to the desired one, so there will be no shifting

Comment: I tried that but as it currently stands, the border will be too long because of the dropdown menu offset.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top` (because margin is outside of the element and breaks hover event):

```
#main-nav ul ul {display:none;position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;padding-top:17px;min-width:150px;}

#main-nav ul ul li {background-color:#000;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);}
```

Also you need to move background declaration from `ul` to `li`'s because of `padding` will move items to desired position, but background would be displayed wrong (right under parent `li`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing `margin-top` with `padding-top` (which requires to change your background settings), just add a spacer element to bridge the gap between parent `li` and dropdown `ul`. See my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZpLf/4/).

Note the extra (empty) div before the `ul`.

Alternatively, if you do not want to add extra elements, use the pseudo selector `:after` on the parent `li` `a` element, see my [second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZpLf/5/). Here's the extra CSS (that's it, no more changes required):

```
#main-nav > ul > li:hover > a:after { 
  content: ""; 
  display: block; 
  min-height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left:0;
  min-width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Do you really think that inserting an empty `div` is good solution? This is like opening fridge with crowbar..